# How do you make the condition true when string includes an element from array? Node.js

Tags: arrays, node.js, string, if-statement, include

How do you make the console print true when the message includes an element from array followed by "are you doing"

Examples:

`message = 'hi, where are you doing' //false`

`message = 'hi, what are you doing' //true`

`message = 'hi, wat are you doing' //true`

`message = 'hi, are you doing what' //false`

```
const array = ['what', 'wat', 'wut']

if (message.includes(array + ' are you doing')) {
  console.log(true)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) has [`.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) that will return `true` if one element in the array satisfies the function you provide.

```
const array = ['what', 'wat', 'wut']

if ( array.some(item => message.includes(`${item} are you doing`)) ) {
  console.log(true)
}
```